# How to create a select, and then an update stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that runs a select query and pulls an id (variable) and then do an update query to that id. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Lead_usp_getLead
    @LeadId int output
AS

   SELECT TOP 1  
       Leadid, LeadInitials, LeadFirstName, LeadSurname, 
       LeadHomeTelephoneNumber, LeadWorkTelephoneNumber,
       LeadCellularNumber, LeadEMailAddress, IsLocked, uploadedDate
   FROM 
       dbo.Lead
   WHERE 
       IsLocked = 'False'
   ORDER BY 
       uploadedDate;

   UPDATE dbo.Lead
   SET IsLocked = 'TRUE'
   WHERE LeadId = @LeadId

   DECLARE @leadid int

   EXEC dbo.Lead_usp_getLead @leadId;
```

Comment: So what is the issue which you are facing?

Comment: The select query runs but the record does not get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just combine them.  No need to do two queries:

```
with toupdate as (
      SELECT TOP 1 l.*
      FROM dbo.Lead l
      WHERE l.IsLocked = 'False'
      ORDER BY l.uploadedDate
     )
Update toupdate
    SET IsLocked = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but how do you suggest I can now get all the values from the select statement?

Comment: @titusx11 . . . Use the `OUTPUT` clause (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand your final result, but:

```
UPDATE dbo.Lead SET IsLocked = 'TRUE'
WHERE Leadid = (SELECT TOP 1 Leadid FROM dbo.Lead WHERE IsLocked = 'False')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of creating a stored procedure is to run a select query and pull an id (variable) and no other complex business logic is to be incorporated .. then you should write a function instead as:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.Lead_fn_getLead', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.Lead_fn_getLead;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Lead_fn_getLead (@LeadId int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @varLeadId int

   SELECT TOP 1  @varLeadId =  
       Leadid
   FROM 
       dbo.Lead
   WHERE 
       IsLocked = 'False'
   ORDER BY 
       uploadedDate;

 RETURN(@varLeadId);
END;
Go
```

and then write as to update the table:

```
DECLARE @leadid int
SET @leadid = 1

UPDATE dbo.Lead
SET IsLocked = 'TRUE'
WHERE LeadId = (Select dbo.Lead_fn_getLead(@leadid))

Go
```

[Check demo here..](http://rextester.com/IHQVK98148)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, it is what I'm looking for however, I need the other fields in the select statement to be returned/displayed if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Well as no other column is being updated except `IsLocked` writing a simple select statement post updation should work as LeadId is going to remain same and `IsLocked` will have it's updated value `TRUE/FALSE` as the case may be..

Comment: Unfortunately I only receive the id, how can I go from there to retrieve the other data for that record.